# Dynamically Add Image To JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I am attempting to dynamically add an image to my JLabel then add the JLabel to my panel.  My code is throwing no errors, but the image is never shown.

```
public JFrameGamePlay(String playername, String playerselected) {
    initComponents();

    playerimage = "/Users/owner/Downloads/__Pikachu.png";
    ImageIcon pimage = new ImageIcon(playerimage);
    JLabel lblPlayer = new JLabel(pimage);
    pnlPlayer.add(lblPlayer);
    pnlPlayer.validate();
    pnlPlayer.repaint();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JFrameGamePlay().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT**
So from further googling I came up with this syntax

```
JLabel lblPlayer;
lblPlayer = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("__Image1.png")));
pnlPlayer.add(lblPlayer);
pnlPlayer.validate();
pnlPlayer.repaint();
```

but when I run the code I get this debug error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
```

This is the GUI layout of how I want my data to appear - it is 1 panel on the left and 1 panel on the right - each with a label dynamically created and populated with an image.  But no image is being populated.
[image]

**EDIT 2**
I added a black border around my 2 Panels, and when the JForm is loaded neither panel is being displayed.  So it seems that what everyone is telling me that GUI designing in NetBeans is pretty buggy.  How can I dynamically in my code behind add the two panels one left and one right with a size of 143, 246?

**EDIT 3**
Still no mustard and I'm using this syntax:

```
public JFrameGamePlay() {
initComponents();
JPanel leftpanel = new JPanel();
JPanel rightpanel = new JPanel();
JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftpanel, rightpanel);

JLabel lblPlayer = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/resources/__Image1.png"));
leftpanel.add(lblPlayer);
leftpanel.validate();
leftpanel.repaint();
```

}

Comment: If Elliott's answer doesn't solve your problem, then you're going to need to post a valid [mcve] with your question, a small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem for us. Please read the link. Also use an image that is available online for ease of testing.

Comment: Call `revalidate` and `repaint` on `pnlPlayer`

Comment: Or better still -- have that JLabel already within the pnlPlayer JPanel, and fill it initially with an ImageIcon that holds a blank image, one that is the size of the player image.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - if I add in pnlPlayer.revalidate(); and pnlPlayer.repaint(); still nothing shows

Comment: @DoctorFord Then I agree with Hovercraft, without more context, there is nothing more we can do for you

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I edit to show my full constructor.  Is there any additional code I can provide for anyone to assist?

Comment: @DoctorFord At a "continuing guess", the layout manager been used (by Netbeans) is the awesome `GroupLayout`, which is notoriously difficult to manage, or worse, it's set to "Absolute Layout", in either case, they are poor choices when you're getting started.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - yes I am using Netbeans.  How do I check if it is in fact GroupLayout

Comment: @DoctorFord Look at the properties editor for the component. Once you've done that, ditch the form editor, they are nothing but trouble when you don't fully understand the API

Comment: @MadProgrammer - looking at the properties of my JPanel I do not see anything that shows GroupLayout...in the code behind can I alter to something other than a GroupLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ImageIO.read(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)) to read the `Image`. Like,

```
File playerimage = new File("/Users/owner/Downloads/__Pikachu.png");
ImageIcon pimage = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(playerimage));
JLabel lblPlayer = new JLabel(pimage);
pnlPlayer.add(lblPlayer);
```

Comment: And of course better to use resources and not files, so when the OP jar's the program.... 1+

Comment: Using this no image shows in my label - same issue as above

Answer (score 0):

The `NullPointerException` comes from the `getResource("__Image1.png")` returning `null` because it didn't find the file. You should prefix it with the location *from the classpath* (after all, the ClassLoader loads the file). E.g. if the image is in a `res` directory in your jar (or in your classpath):

```
JFrameGamePlay.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/res/__Image1.png")));
```

Or you can directly give a complete path:

```
new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/images/thewall.png"));
```

Example:

```
public class JFrameGamePlay extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/images/thewall.png"));
        contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(JFrameGamePlay.class.getResource("/javax/swing/plaf/basic/icons/JavaCup16.png")));
        contentPane.add(label1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: The image is in my resources folder which is a subfolder of the source folder.  I tried to do as you suggested and do /resources/__Image1.png but I still get null exception?  I edit my code to read JLabel lblPlayer = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/resources/__Image1.png")); and there is no error thrown, but the image does not appear when the form loads

Comment: @DoctorFord use `new ImageIcon(class.getResource("/path/relative/to/source/folder/image.png"))` to load from the classpath or `new ImageIcon("/full/path/to/image.png")` to load from the hard drive. Mind that the path might be case-sensitive if you're running on Windows. If the image is in a subfolder of the source folder, then `new JLabel(new ImageIcon(JFrameGamePlay.class.getResource("/resources/__Image1.png")))` should work.

Comment: @DoctorFord try to copy-paste the example I gave, it works (at least with the second image. Use the full path to you `__Image1.png` instead of the `/images/thewall.png` I used).

Answer (score 0):

> My code is throwing no errors, but the image is never added.

Yes, this is unfortunately how ImageIcon works. It doesn't throw exceptions or anything if it's unable to read from the filename or URL you pass to it. The code runs without error but simply shows nothing.

> playerimage = "/Users/owner/Downloads/__Pikachu.png";

If you want to read from a file at a fixed location like this, then it won't be helpful to mess with *getClassLoader().getResource()*. That could be helpful to read an image file that you package with your application, but not to read an image in the user's home directory. Your original *new ImageIcon(imageLocation)* approach is appropriate for that.

[note: I think it's a good idea to send the filename (or URL) directly to the ImageIcon, as your original code does. Other answers suggest ImageIO.read(), which can be helpful to see where it's going wrong, but you could change it back to *ImageIcon(filenameOrUrl)* once you get it working. But it's not a big deal.]

> I am attempting to dynamically add an image to my JLabel then add the JLabel to my panel.

If by "dynamically" you mean to do this when some event occurs, after the panel is already visible on the screen, then I suggest **not** doing that.

That is, instead of doing this...

```
JLabel lblPlayer = new JLabel(pimage);
pnlPlayer.add(lblPlayer);
pnlPlayer.validate();
pnlPlayer.repaint();
```

...you could add the JLabel to your panel (invisible because no text or image) at the very start, before your panel is shown on screen. Then *dynamically* add the ImageIcon to the already-extant JLabel. All you need to call is *existingLabel.setIcon(...)*. There would be no need to call validate() or repaint().

Comment: I like this approach.  How could I set an image from my resource folder to be setIcon?  When I try I am getting compile error of URL can not be converted to icon.  This is my syntax lblPlayer.setIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/__Pikachu.png"));

Comment: Would have to do something like lblPlayer.setIcon( **new ImageIcon(** getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/__Pikachu.png")) );

Comment: That removes the compile error - but I get a debug error of Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Well, we all have to debug NullPointerException sometime. The exception message should have given you a line number to help you track it down. 
One thing you could try is lblPlayer.setIcon(new BallIcon(60, java.awt.Color.ORANGE)) and see if the label stuff works separated from the image loading stuff. [BallIcon.java source](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/0636920043058/blob/master/Learning%20Swing%20GUI%20Programming%20-%20Working%20Files/Chapter%202/BallIcon.java)

Comment: this is pastebin of my full error - can you help me track it down?  It lists multiple line numbers https://pastebin.com/12SCYEQ7